# MongoDB don't throw if $unset array doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an update operation like this:

```
await project.update({
  $pull: {
    languages: { _id: ObjectId(languageId) },
  },
  $unset: {
    [`entries.$[].${languageId}`]: 1,
  },
  $set: {
    revisions: project.revisions,
  },
});
```

However if `entries` array doesn't exist this throws an error:

```
name: 'MongoError',
index: 0,
code: 2,
errmsg: "The path 'entries' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates.",
```

Is there a way to unset if exists but don't throw an error if it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running `update` on `project` document you can run it on [Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) level and add additional condition for `entries` field using [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```
Project.updateOne({ _id: project._id, entries: { $exists: true } } , {
    $pull: {
        languages: { _id: ObjectId(languageId) },
    },
    $set: {
        revisions: project.revisions,
    },
    $unset: {
        [`entries.$[].${languageId}`]: 1
    }
});
```

The problem is that when there's no `entries` then this document won't be matched and none of above operations will be executed.

You could also try to add `$unset` part of your query checking if `project.entries` is not undefined but then you need to be prepared for those errors if some other threads will remove `entries` array in the meantime.